# After Effects - Shape layer obscures graphics layer unless positioned at bottom

Tags: after-effects

I am following an AE tutorial.  As part of its exercise files, the tutorial provides an .ai file that has two layers: a rocket and a black background. The .ai file is then imported into AE as a composition, thereby retaining the two layers.

The tutorial then creates a circle as a shape layer.  It places the shape layer below the rocket but above the background:

[image]

and the following is displayed:

[image]

When I do the same, the circle obstructs the rocket layer:

[image]

The only way I can get the rocket layer to be visible is by moving the circle layer all the way to the vertical bottom:

[image]

It's as if the two layers of the original .ai file are behaving as one.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a dumb question, but is your circle the same colour as the rocket?
Then it would appear to obscure the rocket...

Alternatively - 
There could be some kind of [matte](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/alpha-channels-masks-mattes.html) on one of the layers? 
Click on the Toggle Switches/Modes button at the bottom of the list of layers in the timeline, and see whether any mattes are switched on.

Comment: That was it - white on white!  Thank you so much.  Wish I could upvote x10!

Comment: No worries at all - if you're ever not sure about something like that, switching the "Mask and Shape Visiblity" button on and off can help to see what's going on.  It's Cmd + Shift + H on a mac (ctrl + shift + H on a PC I assume).

Comment: I switched back to white on white to see the effects of toggling "Mask/Shape Visibility".  It did not help.  Sometimes only knowledge from someone experienced as yourself works.  Thank you again. (No wonder BBC production values are high!)